# Classic ASP/VBScript Calculation equals True issue

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a calculation which works perfectly well in Javascript but I need to use it in VBScript/Classic ASP.  All I need to do is work out if all three equal true, then set the result to true.

What am I missing here as there is an error which is claiming it is NULL (which it isn't as I've ouputted the resultset, but for completeness I've manually entered it here so you can see what the complete function is).

```
ry = "0.2911"
rx = "0.7101"
if (ry >= (0.995 - rx)) = True Then
    if (ry >= (0.081 + (0.25 * rx))) = True then
        if (ry <= (0.295)) = True then      
            RedXY = true
        end if
    end if
end if
```

I was under the impression that if any condition was contained with brackets () it would evaluate as either true or false.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly check for `True` it is assumed. Use `If (ry >= (0.995 - rx)) Then` and to check for `False` use `If Not (ry >= (0.995 - rx)) Then`. Also if it's just a case of setting a value to `True` or `False` you can use `RedXY = ((ry >= (0.081 + (0.25 * rx))) And (ry <= (0.295)))` and negate the whole nested `If`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that today, on my 40th Birthday, thickness has set in.

By placing the values with " " I've essentially turned numeric into a string, which won't calculate.  Whoops.....

Comment: Wrapping it with CDbl fixed the problem

Comment: Turns out I have to wait 2 days to answer my own question, knew I should have hung on before posting!